# Remove curly braces block if pattern is found

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I would like to remove a curly braces `{}` block + its "name" (2 word prefix), if a pattern is found inside the block.
I tried some `sed` magic but couldn't get it.
For example:

- Pattern: *PATTERN PATTERN-X*

### Input

```
m m1 {  
    s s1;  
    s s2;  
    c c1 {  
        s s3;   
        c c2 {  
            PATTERN PATTERN-X  
            ...  
        }  
        s s4;
    }  
    c c3 {  
        PATTERN PATTERN-X  
        ...
        c c4 {
            s s4;
        }
    }  
}
```

### Output

```
m m1 {  
    s s1;  
    s s2;  
    c c1 {  
        s s3;   
        s s4;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is that a generalized nagios config file?

Comment: I don't know what _nagios_ is. That's a schema .yang file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this awk

```
awk '
$0~/{/{
  if(b) {
    print b
  b=""
  }
  if(c)
    c++
}
$0~/PATTERN/ {
  b=""
  c=2
}
$0~/}/ {
  if(c)
    c--
}
!c {
  if(b)
    b=b RS
  b=b $0
}
END {
  print b
}
' infile
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have an example this solution doesn't work for. I can't post it in comments becuase the file won't be seen well

Comment: If curly bracket always open and close, we can do something.

Comment: @hudac you're not supposed to post updates in comments. Please edit your question instead, so we all get to see the pathological example.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It works on that example also.

Comment: @ctac_ why does `c=2` in `$0~/PATTERN/ {`, and not `1` ?

Comment: Have you try ? If you start from 1, the last close curly bracket is keep.

Comment: @ctac_ the problem is when I, for example, for another statement after the ` { PATTERN }` block. Try putting `s s4` before line 10. I'll edit the example.

Comment: @ctac_ another problem I see is where the file isn't pretty - if there are more than 1 `curly brace` in a line. i.e. `m m1 { PATTERN P1 }`

Comment: You can use sed 's/{/\n{/g;s/}/\n}/g;s/\(PATTERN PATTERN-X\)/\n&/g' infile | awkscript and replace the line c=2 by c=1. All can certainly be made in awk but i have no time to look much more.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is not good idea to parse any functional language and this example looks like that. Parsing tools were designed to deal with human language where regular expression works fine. With that being said... we still can try.

Here is my approach using `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -Mv '.*{.*\n.*PATTERN(([^{}]|\n)*|([^{}]|\n)*{([^{}]|\n)*}.*([^{}]|\n)*)}.*' file
```

Works fine with your example, i.e. zero or one block `{}` depth after `PATTERN`. If you have more than one block just extend this to suit your needs.

Output:

```
m m1 {  
    s s1;  
    s s2;  
    c c1 {  
        s s3;   
    }  
}
```

Comment: "If you have more than one block just extend this to suit your needs." - In the general case I have `N-depth` blocks